# SQL: Update Column based on another column + other data cleaning

Tags: sql, t-sql

Simplified Question:

```
Material Column='3MR2091' Table Key='1003MR2091 W047F001'
```

What I need is for Table Key to end up being just `'W047'`

What I have so far:

`SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([Table Key],'%F001%',''),[Material],'')
FROM ZMMH03_TEMP;`

Needs to somehow be combined with...

```
SELECT RIGHT([Table Key],LEN([Table Key])-3) As NewTableKey;
SELECT LTRIM([NewTableKey]);
```

.... Holy Cow, I figured it out!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I am a little excited.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT([Table Key],LEN([Table Key])-3),'%F001%',''),[Material],''),' ','') --- Works!!!!!
```

Now Table Key is only the W047 text!

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you check the syntax of the `UPDATE` command?

Comment: What are you using? MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite,...?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Answer (score 0):

just use update statement for your table based on your column

```
update [YourTable] set [Table Key] = [Material]  where [your condition]
```

or

```
   update [YourTable] set [Table Key] = ''  where [Material] = ''
```

not sure what you need exactly so i wrote for you both variants

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you are using T-SQL...

```
UPDATE [YOUR TABLE]
SET [TABLE KEY] = REPLACE([TABLE KEY], MATERIAL,'')
```

This will look for the value in `MATERIAL` inside the value of `[TABLE KEY]` and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Yes, except I don't use the WHERE statement since the Material is duplicated in the Table Key.

Comment: @GregBarnett: Then you can ignore the where statement. It should work (but better to be safe than sorry: Test it with a SELECT first ;) )

Comment: Agreed, and Thank You! I love this site. I know it may not look like it from my question above, but up until this point, I have been able to find answers to all my questions here. This file is just formatted horribly, the way I receive it. And I don't have any control over the format from the source.